# VueJS Transitions on Table Cells

Tags: vue.js, transition, vuex

I'm trying to get transitions to work on table cell elements in VueJS, and having them work on items that get changed within an object.  I'm using Vuex for the data store, and I can't seem to get them to work either on the individual cell ([See Fiddle 1)](https://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/7cyvbxjL/)

```js
// This call state data.
const state = {
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Hello',
    name: 'Bill'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'There',
    name: 'Diane'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'My',
    name: 'John'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'Name',
    name: 'Anne'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    text: 'is',
    name: 'Fred'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    text: 'Hello',
    name: 'Yasmine'
  }, ]
}

// This is look like events.
const mutations = {
  UPDATEITEM(state, item) {
    var changedItem = state.items.find((checkItem) => {
      return checkItem.id == item.id;
    });
    if (item.text) {
      changedItem.text = item.text;
    } else if (item.name) {
      changedItem.name = item.name;
    }
  },
}

// This is store!!!.
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  getters: {
    items: function(state) {
      return state.items
    }
  },
  // Call action to dispatch 
  actions: {
    UPDATEITEM: function(store, item) {
      store.commit('UPDATEITEM', item)
    }
  }
})

// Vue 
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    id: 3,
    name: '',
    text: ''
  },
  store,
  methods: {
    changeName: function() {
      const item = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name
      };
      this.$store.dispatch('UPDATEITEM', item);

    },
    changeText: function() {
      const item = {
        id: this.id,
        text: this.text
      };
      this.$store.dispatch('UPDATEITEM', item);
    },
    getItemById: function(id) {
      var item = this.items.find((checkItem) => {
        return checkItem.id == id;
      });
      if (item) {
        return item;
      } else {
        return {
          name: ''
        };
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.items;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
  .update-enter-active {
        transition: all .5s ease-in;
    }

    .update-leave-active {
        transition: all .5s ease-out;
    }

    .update-enter, .update-leave-to {
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: #fd0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.0/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>message</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td><transition name="update"><span :key="item.id + '-name'">{{item.name}}</span></transition></td>
        <td><transition name="update"><span :key="item.id + '-text'">{{item.text}}</span></transition></td>          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </ul>
  <div>
    User id:
    <input v-model="id">
    {{getItemById(id).name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Change Name:
    <input v-model="name" v-on:keyup.enter="changeName">
  </div>
  <div>
    Change Text:
    <input v-model="text" v-on:keyup.enter="changeText">
  </div>

</div>
```

or on a transition group for the row ([See Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/rt095sww/)):

```js
// This call state data.
const state = {
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Hello',
    name: 'Bill'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'There',
    name: 'Diane'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'My',
    name: 'John'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'Name',
    name: 'Anne'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    text: 'is',
    name: 'Fred'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    text: 'Hello',
    name: 'Yasmine'
  }, ]
}

// This is look like events.
const mutations = {
  UPDATEITEM(state, item) {
    var changedItem = state.items.find((checkItem) => {
      return checkItem.id == item.id;
    });
    if (item.text) {
      changedItem.text = item.text;
    } else if (item.name) {
      changedItem.name = item.name;
    }
  },
}

// This is store!!!.
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  getters: {
    items: function(state) {
      return state.items
    }
  },
  // Call action to dispatch 
  actions: {
    UPDATEITEM: function(store, item) {
      store.commit('UPDATEITEM', item)
    }
  }
})

// Vue 
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    id: 3,
    name: '',
    text: ''
  },
  store,
  methods: {
    changeName: function() {
      const item = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name
      };
      this.$store.dispatch('UPDATEITEM', item);

    },
    changeText: function() {
      const item = {
        id: this.id,
        text: this.text
      };
      this.$store.dispatch('UPDATEITEM', item);
    },
    getItemById: function(id) {
      var item = this.items.find((checkItem) => {
        return checkItem.id == id;
      });
      if (item) {
        return item;
      } else {
        return {
          name: ''
        };
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.items;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
  .update-enter-active {
        transition: all .5s ease-in;
    }

    .update-leave-active {
        transition: all .5s ease-out;
    }

    .update-enter, .update-leave-to {
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: #fd0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.0/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>message</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody name="update" is="transition-group">
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.text}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </ul>
  <div>
    User id:
    <input v-model="id"> 
    {{getItemById(id).name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Change Name:
    <input v-model="name" v-on:keyup.enter="changeName">
  </div>
  <div>
    Change Text:
    <input v-model="text" v-on:keyup.enter="changeText">
  </div>

</div>
```

Is it just not possible to do transitions with members of an object (text, name), or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this key:

```
<td><transition name="update">
  <span :key="item.name">{{item.name}}</span>
</transition></td>
```

Comment: Why does this key (:key="item.name"), and not :key="item.id + '-name'" not work?  And why when value of item.name is the same on multiple rows do we not see multiple transitions occur?

Comment: I wasn't aware of use of :key with transition, just stumbled on it! (LOL). If you put :key="id" (the local var) then the whole table flashes on change of id input, so I concluded :key indicates the thing to be watched.

Comment: BTW, thanks for providing a fiddle to experiment with.